# Error on opening matlab related to null

Tags: java, matlab, ubuntu, nvidia

After i installed matlab R2017a in ubuntu mate 17.04, when i opened it, in command window it returns error in red color:

```
Caught throwable while adding doc set item to doc set builder: null
```

I don't understand what this is. I have nvidia drivers. How to resolve this issue?

I will post additional required info like my settings etc. if needed.